# Algorithm vs Code

Tags: coding-style, software-design

I came across the declaration in a software best practices guide that **algorithm and code shouldn't get mixed up**. I'm not sure what is meant by this? As far as I understand, code is the implementation of the algorithm, isn't is? So, what exactly is meant by this statement? and why it is considered as a good practice?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context in which the author mentioned would be clearer if you had pasted the surrounding lines. 
Though what it would mean to me is, an algorithm is just a clear step-by-step logic that you would use to implement. You would leave out the finer implementation details like selection of the right data structure and other implementation details while you write/design the algorithm.

Comment: I agree with this. I'd assume it's more related to to creation of an algorithm and keeping it code agnostic rather than the creation of the code itself.

Comment: @Gargi: I certainly would have done so, but this was in a point form. Anyway it should be what u explained above, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A good explanation can be found [here](https://simplicable.com/new/algorithm-vs-code)

> An **algorithm** is a series of steps for solving a problem, completing a task or performing a calculation. Algorithms are usually executed by computer programs but the term can also apply to steps in domains such as mathematics for human problem solving.
>
> **Code** is a series of steps that machines can execute. In many cases, code is composed in a high level language that is then automatically translated into instructions that machines understand.